# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

I created a DialogFragment.
The Dialog got a EditText and I call it from the dialog xml.
But there is the error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

New in this code:

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

and

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordDeveloper);
```

My Code:

```
public class DeveloperLoginDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

EditText editText;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final LayoutInflater inflaterDialog = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alertDialog = builder.create();

   // final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setView(inflaterDialog.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_developer, null));
    final EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordDeveloper);
    builder.setTitle("Entwickler-Login");
    builder.setMessage("Um dich als Entwickler zu verifizieren, gib den Entwickler-Code bitte unten ein.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Verifizieren", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().equals("7846")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Erfolgreich verifiziert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Comment: You are calling `findViewById` on an object before assigning any value to it. Perhaps you wanna assign value of `inflaterDialog.inflate` to a View variable and then do `view.findViewById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is simple you are using the edit text to find a view. You have two options either inflate a layout then use findViewById or use the alertDialog.findViewById();

try this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FeedFragment.this.getActivity());
    builder.setView(R.layout.layout_edit_review);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    TextInputEditText text_edit = (TextInputEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editReview);
```

try something like that.

Comment: Thanks! But now it says: ttempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: first set the view for the builder.then call findViewById

Comment: It is because .getText()

Comment: if you refactored the code, the get text function should work.

Comment: I have entered it above

Comment: Hey, show me the new changes to code.

Comment: See it above (again). The problem is the error message: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: oh i see the problem, you are calling create before you set the view. set the view then call create on builder. Create method registers and links the layout, if you create then add layout it wont work.

Comment: is it working now after changing the statements?

Answer (score 1):

`editText = (EditText) editText.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordDeveloper);`

You are calling `findViewById()` on `editText` which is null. You probably want to use `EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.label_field);` instead.

Note the use of `alertDialog` rather than `editText`.